# Set the Button Control to fit on screen whatever the screen device resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-button

Here I am trying to create an UI for Android app. I have several buttons and logo at the top. while designing app I found that blank space at the bottom of buttons. I want to use that space so that all the buttons are align properly inside the blank area. Buttons are design from below from logo to button of the device screen.

[image] 
I have done this code

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0B95BA"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_container">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="87.5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/LogoHere"
        android:id="@+id/imgLogoHere"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgLogoHere"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/scrollView">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnVisit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:text="Visit"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:text="Our"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnOur"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:text="Ours"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnOurs"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:text=" Contact Us"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnContactUs"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:text="Test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/btnTest"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:text="View"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOrderEntry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:text="Order Entry"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnIntranet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
                android:text="Intranet"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Form Image it more clear I want to be a buttons are displayed on blank area on any device so that User can not feel uncomfortable. while using the app.

Or please suggest me any thing that can be load UI on the screen and fit to dispaly dynamically whatever the device resolution.

Thanks in advanace

Comment: give margin to each button & it will cover bottom space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
android:fillViewport="false"
```

to

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

in your **scrollView**. You are not allowing `scrollView` to fill your device screen that is why you are seeing blank space.

[image: scrollview]

Answer (score 2):

> Add `android:layout_margin="10dp"` **or** `android:layout_margin="12dp"`

For each `Button`.

**Refer this.**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIntranet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Intranet"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

> Do the same for all the `Buttons`.

Comment: thanks for your replay. Do you have any idea so that Shall I make it dynamically for any device.

Comment: @MartinP You have used `Scroll View` in your `Layout` so it will not have any problem working with any of the Resolution user can scroll and can view easily.

Comment: One thing I like to ask How I can increase the button size means you can see the image button height is so small on device its difficult to read the text how I can increase it

Comment: @MartinP I guess you don't have any problem with scroll view at starting of activity you want to fill the items to whole screen right.

Answer (score 1):

Since your layout is very linear, it's better to use a `LinearLayout` as the root tag.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    other attributes here...>

</LinearLayout>
```

This means you can remove all the relative layout related stuff its children, such as `layout_below`.

Add a `weight` to your image view, and set it to 2 or any other number that looks good. And of course, set its height to 0dp.

Add a weight to the scroll view. I think 8 will be fine. Also set the height to 0dp

Change the height of the linear layout (the one in the scroll view!) to `match_parent`.

I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can control your widgets layout properties from your java code for different screen resolutions.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float requiredHeight = (screenHeight * 1) / 8;
final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int buttonHeight = (int) ((int) requiredHeight * scale + 0.5f);
buttonName.setHeight(buttonHeight );
```

Set height property for all your buttons.